# How to build image with snapshot of filesystem after CMD run in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to build an image of my frontend app. The goal is to make image with all bundles created by bundler webpack.
Dockerfile

```
FROM node:12
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./ ./
RUN npm install
CMD npm run build
```

Command `npm run build` generates bundles but they are not included in resulting image. So my question is: Is there way to create image with filesystem snapshot after CMD was executed

Comment: If you change `CMD` to `RUN`, it will get built as part of your `docker build` sequence, and you can add a `CMD` that actually launches the (built) application.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thank you! If you post this as answer I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CMD` is actually the wrong command here. And you should use `RUN` instead.

The `CMD` defines what is executed when you start the docker-image as a container. This means when you execute `docker run -d your-image` it will start a container which is created from the image `your-image` and then executing the the command specified by `CMD`. You can overwrite this at starttime by adding another command to the docker run like this: `docker run -d your-image sh -c 'echo a && echo b'`

But as mentioned the solution to your problem is using `RUN`.

If you want to learn more about this I would recommend reading the [docs of docker regarding the Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run).

Comment: Actually what he should do is to combine both command into a single `RUN` layer: `RUN npm install && npm run build`. One should always strive to have the last possible amount of layers in the final image.

Comment: Correct, however the only reason his image was not in the expected state was the described misunderstanding. Therefore this is not the deal-breaker here.